# MySQL update returns 0 rows affected

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update mysql query but it returns 0 rows affected I don't know whats wrong with it here is my query

```
UPDATE tblbikesdata SET SoldStatus='1' WHERE BikeID='1' AND EngineNo='e1' AND ChassisNo='chssis4'
```

Here is my result

```
[SQL]UPDATE tblbikesdata SET SoldStatus='1' WHERE BikeID='1' AND EngineNo='e1' AND ChassisNo='chssis4'

Affected rows: 0
Time: 0.001s
```

Comment: Try select with the same where clause.

Comment: Can you check "SELECT * FROM tblbikesdata WHERE BikeID='1' AND EngineNo='e1' AND ChassisNo='chssis4'", If it will display 0 rows then of course 0 row affected while updating, Because there isn't any row available which match your `WHERE` condition

Comment: The answer you accepted is in fact wrong. You should consider accepting one that’s correct (like mine) so future readers aren’t led astray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because there is no such a row

```
WHERE BikeID='1' AND EngineNo='e1' AND ChassisNo='chssis4'
```

is.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and should not have the green check. As I say in my answer,  this can also happen if there is a matching row but the new field values provided in the UPDATE match the old field values, MySQL will report that as no rows affected.

Answer (score 10):

The answer from @monkey-supersonic is incorrect.

You can see an `Affected rows: 0` response either (1) by the WHERE condition not being met, or (2) the new values you provide are the same as the current values that already exist in the matching record(s).

You can't assume no matches to the WHERE clause just because there are no affected rows.